# Problems with TextView align right in android

Tags: android, alignment

I would like to ask how to change the layout to get TextView with ID rowType set to absolute right position. Currently I have set gravity to right, but current setting align in to right of the TextView above (id: row). So in case TextView row ends at half of the screen, TextView rowType ends at half...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@color/notepad_paper">
  <TableRow 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
      android:fadingEdge="vertical" 
      android:fadeScrollbars="true" 
      android:gravity="left" 
      android:layout_gravity="left|center_horizontal">
      <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/rowImgFav" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:fadingEdge="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      /> 
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/rowImg" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:fadingEdge="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      />

        <TableLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <TableRow 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                >
                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/row"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/notepad_text" /> 
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rowType"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@color/notepad_text" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout> 
  </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@color/notepad_paper">
  <TableRow 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
      android:fadingEdge="vertical" 
      android:fadeScrollbars="true" 
      android:gravity="left" 
      android:layout_gravity="left|center_horizontal">
      <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/rowImgFav" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:fadingEdge="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      /> 
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/rowImg" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:fadingEdge="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      />

        <TableLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1">
            <TableRow 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                >
                <TextView 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:textStyle="bold" 
                android:textSize="14dp" 
                android:paddingLeft="10dp" 
                android:textColor="@color/notepad_text" 
                android:paddingBottom="0dp" 
                android:id="@+id/row" 
                android:layout_weight="1.0"></TextView> 
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rowType"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@color/notepad_text"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"/>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout> 
  </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Fixed! I have added `android:layout_weight="1.0"`!

Comment: Yeah, weight is handy. Also, TableRows align themselves with eachother. Doing something like this I would probably have gone for a RelativeLayout instead.

Comment: Yeah ... I was thinking about RelativeLayout too... But have some other limitations as well... TableLayout did just perfect now!